# Problem on Solving Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(Xt)$ be a solution to the equation

$dX_t = aX_t dt + \sqrt{(1+X_t^2)} dW_t$ where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion process at time t

Let $Y = F(X_t)$ for a certain function $F$. Find $F$ for which $(Y_t) solves the equation

$dY_t = f(Y_t) dt + dW_t$

where the drift term f should be explicitly determined. You may use the fact that

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\ = ln (x + \sqrt{1+x^2}).
$$

**My attempt**

$dY_t = dF(X_t)$

Applying ito's formula we obtain.

$dF(X_t) = F'(X_t) dX_t + 1/2 F''(X_t)(dX_t)^2$

Substituting $dX_t$ and $(dX_t)^2$

$dF(X_t) = F'(X_t) (aX_tdt + \sqrt{1+X^2_t} dW_t) + \frac{1}{2} F''(X_t)(1+X^2_t)dt$
$dF(X_t) = F'(X_t)(aX_t + \frac{1}{2} F''(X_t)(1+X^2_t)) dt + F'(X_t)\sqrt{1+X^2_t} dW_t$

Equating coefficients for $dW_t$

$F'(X_t)\sqrt{1+X^2_t} = 1$

$F(X_t) = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}}dx$

$F(X_t) = ln (X_t + \sqrt{1+X_t^2}) + C$, where C is a constant

**Now my question is**; Can we find this constant? If not, is the answer above correct for $F(x)
$
now after equating the coefficients of $dt$, the drift term f is

$f(Y_t) = f(F(X_t)) = aX_t + \frac{1}{2} F''(X_t)(1+X^2_t)$

**Question**; How can I find the function f?

Comment: "Deleted till tommorrow 5.00pm AEST. Answer will reappear then" What is going on?

Comment: Don't want teacher to think that I plagarised from my initial answer.

Comment: What is *your* initial answer? There is only one answer here, still visible, not due to you but @Ian, still available for every *plagiarism* one can imagine.

Comment: Ian's response reaffirms my answer. He says that "my solution is correct" to the equation for F(X_t). I also ask several other questions which is why Ian's answer looks a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: I still fail to get why you deleted the question (which is still visible to quite a few of users anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You find
$$
F(X_t) = \ln \left(X_t + \sqrt{1+X_t^2}\right) + C,
$$
for any constant $C$. In fact, for all such constants, $(Y_t)$ will satisfy the expected stochastic differential equation, with initial value $Y_0=\ln \left(X_0 + \sqrt{1+X_0^2}\right) + C$.

Afterwards, you made a typo when writing $f(Y_t)$, it should be
$$
f(Y_t) = f(F(X_t)) = aX_t\mathbf{F'(X_t)} + \frac{1}{2} F''(X_t)(1+X^2_t).
$$
Simple computations show that 
$$
F'(X_t)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}},\text{ and }F''(X_t)=-X_t\left(1+X_t^2\right)^{-3/2},
$$
and therefore,
$$
f(F(X_t))=\left(a-\frac12\right)\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}}.
$$
Lastly, it remains to note that $\ln \left(X_t + \sqrt{1+X_t^2}\right)=\sinh^{-1}(X_t)$, so
$$
f(Y_t)=\left(a-\frac12\right)\tanh\left(Y_t-C\right)=\left(a-\frac12\right)\tanh\left(Y_t-Y_0+\ln \left(X_0 + \sqrt{1+X_0^2}\right)\right).
$$